# PDFTK Script to split all files within a folder - noob

Tags: windows, powershell, pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

Want a script to run and split all files in a folder to 1 page PDF documents then move them to another folder. I'm on windows and I'm a noob and need some assistance. The below code works but I cannot wildcard all PDF files.  Get-ChildItem -File | Foreach {c:\test*.PDF} doesn't work with PDFTK?

The below script works

```html
cmd /c "for %s in (c:\test*.pdf) do pdftk %s burst output c:\pdftest\%~ns_%02d.pdf"
```

Comment: I can't see what this has to do woth Ghostscript.....

Comment: GS does have some PDF splitting capabilities. that I've briefly looked into. I have another script running through GS but it's for converting files rather than splitting them.

Comment: Ghostscript can easily do this yes, just put %d in the OutputFilename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this again, I can't see any reason why you can't do this with simple shell programming. Something like:

for %s in (c:\test*.pdf) do pdftk %s burst output c:\pdftest\%~ns_%02d.pdf

ought to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on linux :(.

Comment: @Destryo you can do this is wondows with `cmd` and `bash`. To do a bash command do `bash -c "for %s in (c:\test*.pdf) do pdftk %s burst output c:\pdftest\%~ns_%02d.pdf"` and to do a cmd command do `cmd /c "for %s in (c:\test*.pdf) do pdftk %s burst output c:\pdftest\%~ns_%02d.pdf"`

Comment: Neko, This worked. I did find another way to do it using another module. I now need to figure out how to delete a split file.